# Is this plain form "I requested her hand for marriage from her father" acceptable in general; as opposed to the idiomatic form?

Tags: idioms, formality

The plain form which I feel more natural to my tongue:

> I requested her hand for marriage from her father

As opposed to the idiomatic form:

> I asked her father for her hand in marriage

Is the plain form acceptable in place of the idiomatic form; at least informally?

Comment: It's always "her hand **in** marriage". That's a fixed phrase.

Comment: In most Anglophone communities, even the *concept* of asking for the father's permission to marry his daughter is outdated, so there isn't really any meaning to asking whether the outdated idiom *[ask for her] **hand in marriage*** would be "acceptable" in an ***informal*** context (unless the whole point of using it was to be facetious).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yep, it's more "correct" to ask for the father's "blessing", though even that might be considered weird in the specific community involved.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's still considered a nice formality in some communities. I don't know if you can unequivocally state that there is no English-speaking community anywhere in the world where this is not a serious question. And in any case, you don't know whether the OP is talking about a contemporary situation or an historical one.

Comment: @Jay: I don't know if you can unequivocally state things like that either - but my guess is probably *not*, which is why I said ***most** Anglophone communities*. And *if* OP's actually talking about a "historical" context their would obviously be no problem in using what I referred to as an ***outdated*** idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the concept of asking a father for his daughter's hand in marriage feels dated to many of us, there are nevertheless many communities around the world where this practice is commonplace.   There are many ways to phrase it, but the idiomatic expression will always be "hand **in** marriage".

> He asked for her **hand in marriage**.
>
> He asked her father for her **hand in marriage**.
>
> He requested her **hand in marriage** from her father.

and so on.  All of these would be considered "formal" because "hand in marriage" is a formal expression.